# How do I migrate workbench states?

Tags: 8, migrations, upgrading, workbench

I have used the [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench) module in my Drupal 7 website.

Now I want to migrate this website to Drupal 8. But when I migrate the site, it migrates only content and not the workbench states that were created for contents.

Any help?

Comment: What are you using to manage moderation states in D8 - do you have Workbench there as well, or another module? It looks like the current [8.x-1.x branch of Workbench](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/workbench/tree/?h=8.x-1.x) has no migration support.

Comment: I have mentioned that I am using Workbench module. By the thanks for reply, We need to do customise it.